# How do I add trackable to an existing Devise setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Im trying to get the last sign in date time in RoR application using Devise gem. In one of my migration files I noticed the `# t.datetime :last_sign_in_at` field among others:

```
## Trackable
  # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
  # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  # t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  # t.string   :last_sign_in_ip
```

So the question is: how to activate this field for my users to be able to call it later in my app? Should I just uncomment that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First, you need to generate a new migration:

```
rails generate migration AddDeviseTrackableColumnsToUsers \
sign_in_count:integer \
current_sign_in_at:datetime \
last_sign_in_at:datetime \
current_sign_in_ip:string \
last_sign_in_ip:string
```

then replace:

`add_column :users, :sign_in_count, :integer`

with:

`add_column :users, :sign_in_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false`

Now the migration file looks like:

```
class AddDeviseTrackableColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :users, :sign_in_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false
    add_column :users, :current_sign_in_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :last_sign_in_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :current_sign_in_ip, :string
    add_column :users, :last_sign_in_ip, :string
  end
end
```

Run `rails db:migrate`

In the user model *app/models/user.rb*, ensure that `:trackable` option is added to the `devise` method:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable
end
```

The enabled options may be different in your case, just add `:trackable` if you didn't find it.

Now you can use `last_sign_in_at` attribute like other attributes.