# Rails 7 + devise + devise_ldap_authenticatable: before_save issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap, ruby-on-rails-7

I wrote an app in Rails 7 + devise + devise_ldap_authenticatable

My User model looks like this.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :ldap_authenticatable

  before_save :get_from_ldap

  def get_from_ldap
    puts '1 ##########################################'
    self.username = <WHAT EVER CODE>
    puts '2 ##########################################'
  end
end
```

This works perfectly but just one time. The first time, when the user is created into the DB after the first login.

I'm not sure but I think this is related with some *devise_ldap_authenticatable* directive because before_save is usually called always rigth?

```rb
config.ldap_create_user = true
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I would like some method o technique to do that every time a user login to be sure I get all changes from the Active Directory.

Thanks.

#### UPDATE ### :

I tried with *before_validation* and *after_validation* and all these callbacks are called just once. First time the user log in and is created into DB. This is not normal rigth? Any idea?

My devise.rb

```rb
  # ==> LDAP Configuration
  config.ldap_logger = true
  config.ldap_create_user = true
  config.ldap_update_password = false
  config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
  config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
  # config.ldap_ad_group_check = false

  # Sin esta linea trata de buscar por mail en vez de por el atributo definido en
  # config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
  # 
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121543/rails-devise-ldap-authentication-cannot-find-user
  #
  config.ldap_auth_username_builder = Proc.new() {|attribute, login, ldap| login}
```

My ldap,yml

```yaml
## Authorizations
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
  allow_unauthenticated_bind: false

development:
  host: 13.0.0.1
  port: 389
  attribute: userPrincipalName
  group_membership_attribute: member
  base: dc=mydomain,dc=net
  admin_user: cn=Admin,ou=Users,ou=first,dc=mydomain,dc=net
  admin_password: ***********
  ssl: false
  # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. The callback is only called on **save** ( of course ). In my use case that is only on the first login when the every user is created. Nexts logins never update the DB, so save is never called.

To fix it, I thought a way to force that update.

[Devise trackable](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/main/Devise/Models/Trackable) module is my solution. Thanks to [How do I add trackable to an existing Devise setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024228/how-do-i-add-trackable-to-an-existing-devise-setup)

If I add **:trackable** to my User model, the callback is called every login.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :ldap_authenticatable, :trackable

  before_save :get_from_ldap


  def get_from_ldap

    self.username = self.email.split('@')[0]

    # Se recuperan todos los grupos a los que pertenece el usuario
    groups = self.ldap_groups


    <MY CODE>    


    self.role = <ROLE FROM MY CODE>

  end
end
```